# How to successfully run corepack enable in terminal

Tags: terminal, corepack

I am trying to run `corepack enable` in my MacBook terminal and I am getting the below error. I am not entirely sure what the issue is

````
Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/pnpm.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/pnpm'```

I am trying to run that command in my CLI
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are encountering this error is because you are being denied access. To enable you to run the command successfully do this

```
sudo corepack enable
```

It will ask you for your password after you hit enter.